# Syncing profile details with active directory

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, user-profile

Several fields in MOSS profiles are mapped to fields in active directory and we have given the user the ability to modify these.

But when the incremental profile import runs it overwrites these with the old values from active directory.

How do we make it so that AD is updated with the new values from the profile?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

From http://blog.seancleaver.com/sean_cleaver/2008/07/sync-ad-users-to-sharepoint---2-way.html

So some of you have requested support to provide 2-Way Synchronization of AD Users between a SharePoint List and Active Directory. The good news is that the AD Provider for Data [Synchronization Studio](http://www.simego.com/DataSync_Studio.aspx) now supports this.

So you can effectively publish your AD Users to an Intranet Site to create a "Staff List" or "Telephone List" and then from this you can now allow your staff to update the personal information stored in the AD themselves by just simply editing the records in SharePoint. Then when the Synchronization occurs all changes are applied to the AD. There are a few limitations you can't create new AD Users this way and you can't delete users from the AD and certain properties are not updateable such as Member-Of etc.

Answer (score 0):

We've given up on an easy way to do this and are writing a scheduled task that gets the recent change info from the users profile and updates AD from that.

Will try to post code once I've got something working.